# window.URL.CreateObject(blob) returns unexpected identifier

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have this code :

```
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then(resp => resp.blob())
        .then(blob => {
            console.log(blob); //Has Value
            const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            console.log(url); // This is throwing the error
            const a = document.createElement('a');
            a.style.display = 'none';
            a.href = url;
            a.download = 'todo-1.json';
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            alert('your file has downloaded!');
        }).catch((error) => {
           alert('oh no!')
          console.log(error);}
       );
```

[image]

on the javascript console in google chrome i tried running this code and it is running smoothly. But in salesforce I don't know why does it throw me an unexpected identifier I have already put the site to the CSP.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research on this and here comes the problem !!
I can see the response type of the service https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1 is application/json. Ideally, you should first resolve the readable stream based on type of service that is returning (in this case it is json) and then convert to whatever the type you want(here it is blob).

Please see the below one which is working

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(data => {
            var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(data)], {type : "application/json"});
            console.log(blob); //Has Value
            const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            console.log(url); // This is throwing the error
            const a = document.createElement('a');
            a.style.display = 'none';
            a.href = url;
            a.download = 'todo-1.json';
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            alert('your file has downloaded!');
        }).catch((error) => {
           alert('oh no!')
          console.log(error);}
       );
```

Let me know if it helps!!

Comment: Still throwing an error :( on the log...

Comment: @xSkrappy can you let me know is that the same error or any new error this time? I’ve tested it and it’s downloaded.

Comment: Its the same. What Bundle version Are you using?

Comment: I'm using 46 version.